# Call BAPI RFCs transactionally via JCo

Tags: java, saprfc, jco, bapi

First of all I'm not a SAP/BAPI developer.
We have a java application that is calling some BAPIs over RFCs using JCo library.
The question is whether there is any way to call several of those in a single transaction.

I believe the correct way to do it would be to

- begin JCoContext
- execute some RFCs
- call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT
- end JCoContext

E.g. we'd like to call those system bapis this way:
BAPI_CATIMESHEETMGR_INSERT
BAPI_CATIMESHEETMGR_CHANGE

But for some reason all the stuff gets commited regardless of what we do.
I would like to understand what exactly is commiting this data. Are commits part of those BAPIs or is it some kind of JCo "feature"?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. A BAPI should not commit data, but there are a few exceptions. Only `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` should do that. But if you want to revert the updates, you should call `BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK` otherwise that would do an implicit commit at the end of context. Opening and closing a context should open an independent transaction. If you can run a trace from SAP, with transaction code `ST05` and with the "call stack" logging option, you could see the ABAP origin of the commit.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start learning the RFC transaction model is [this piece of help](http://saphelp.ucc.ovgu.de/NW750/EN/4d/4f424ab3ee468de10000000a42189c/frameset.htm), where you can read the guidelines about creating custom BAPIs:

> BAPIs must not execute 'COMMIT WORK' commands.
> Reason: The caller should have control of the transaction. Several BAPIs should be able to be combined within one LUW. For more information see Transaction Model for Developing BAPIs.
> The following commands must not be used:
>
> - CALL TRANSACTION
> - SUBMIT REPORT
> - SUBMIT REPORT AND RETURN
>   Database changes can only be made through updates.
>   **Reason: The RFC executes an implicit database commit**.

So yes, generally your assumption is correct, the implicit commit happens in RFC.

Moreover, ["Transaction Model for Developing BAPIs" help section](http://saphelp.ucc.ovgu.de/NW750/EN/4d/4f424ab3ee468de10000000a42189c/frameset.htm) contains important notes about your scenario:

> The following restrictions apply to combining several BAPIs in one LUW:
>
> - If an instance was created, modified or deleted by a write BAPI, a read BAPI can only access the most recent data if a COMMIT WORK has taken place.
> - **It is not possible to make two write accesses on the same instance within one LUW. For example, you cannot first create and then change the object within the same LUW.**
> - You can, however, create several instances of the same object type within an LUW.

So you will not be able to achieve what you want: create (BAPI_CATIMESHEETMGR_INSERT) and change (BAPI_CATIMESHEETMGR_CHANGE) timesheet in one LUW ([Logical Unit of Work](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_snc700_ehp01/helpdata/en/41/7af4bca79e11d1950f0000e82de14a/content.htm?no_cache=true)).

It must be done in two LUWs (two RFC calls).